# Adapting Maine's Dirigo motto to say something like "I lead the bored"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

“Dirigo” is the Maine state motto. It’s generally translated as “I lead”. Well, I’ve got a chance to name a bit of land here and I want it's motto to be in Latin and to express something like “I lead the bored”—‘bored', suggesting a lack of anything interesting to do.

Now, I took Latin school but it has been 25 years ago and it’s nearly all deserted by brain. I hope the help I get here is just someone telling me what’s right and what’s wrong, without asking many questions that I do not know the meaning to.